# Adding JComment extension to Virtuemart product detail page

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

I wanna add JComment to appear not only in article pages, but on Virtuemart product detail too. 
How can i do that?

I have another extension named "addtoany" that shows social media buttons. 
I want to do the same thing to this extension too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first... As per official Stack Exchange Help, you should never ask two different things in one Question, even if they appear to be closely related. One question should be for one inquiry only.

Regarding your inquiry about JComments integration into Virtuemart, you haven't mentioned their versions you are using, and that is crucially important for answering it correctly.
So, I am providing a very simple but long-sought-after solution for VM 3.0.12+ and Joomla 3.4.8+, which I have successfully implemented yesterday at one of my client's shops.

1. Go to this VM Forum post 
   '*[VirtueMart 2.0.3c+ - JComments 2.3.0 Integration (Free). For J 1.7 and 2.5](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=99683.30)*', jump to the last (third) page, and in the last post from user 'Studio 42' posted on 2016-03-14 you will find the link to his '*[JComments fork on GitHub](http://github.com/studio42-fork/jcomments)*'.
   Simply download this extension (I call it `com_jcomments_3.0.5_fork_j25j3x.zip`) and install it. 
   This guy from http://st42.fr rewrote few things in latest official `com_jcomments_v3.0.5.zip`, and added new Content Plugin `plg_vmjcomments` 'Virtuemart 3 - JComments Content Plugin' which handles attaching jcomments layout to the long product description in VM Product Detail page.
   I have tested it and it is working flawlessly on two sites and in two different templates.
2. After this installation you should configure few things right away, in order to enable this whole enchilada: Go to VM Configuration|Configuration section and:

   - on Shop tab set Enable Joomla Plugin ON, in order to enable aforementioned content plugin in VM product description field.
   - on Shopfront tab, in Shopper Review/Rating System section set all four settings to 'Don't show' and 'Disabled', in order to disable VM built-in comments/ratings. You can't have it active while using JComments.
3. For latest VM and Joomla that's all you need to do. Don't follow other older posts in this topic, unless you are using old VM 2 and Joomla 2.5, which you are not... right?!? :-)
4. You can safely install any other module/plugin from [Official JComments Download section](http://www.joomlatune.com/jcomments-downloads.html), and use them as you wish.
5. On a side note, we all should be aware that JComments is a 'dead fish'! The guy stopped updating it almost two years ago, and it is yet another great extension which didn't survive in this Open Source Warfare...

Regarding your second inquiry about "addtoany" social media buttons, I have never used it even though I know there is a Joomla plugin for it. I guess VM implementation should go along adding calls to plugin into VM product detail layout overrides in your template, but don't
hold me to it.

Comment: I'm using the last version of Joomla and Jcomments. Thanks alot, it worked.. but how can i make the jcomment appear at the bottom of the product detail page?

Comment: Glad it worked! But I would assume jcomment layout appears at the bottom of product detail page. This whole solution makes exactely that. You can see my implementation at following links http://www.prodavnicazdravehrane.rs/prodavnica/namena/za-vegansku-ishranu/kokosovo-ulje-organsko-ekstra-devicansko-detalji and http://www.beyondhealthfood.com/nasi-artikli/jestiva-ulja/kokosovo-ulje-organsko-ekstra-devicansko-detail . On both of them jcomments layout is at the bottom of product detail, without any intervention of mine, other than strictly following this solution.

Comment: how do u think i can solve this problem? in the back-end of joomla or by writing some js codes or etc ?

Comment: Problem Solved. I edited in com_virtuemart\productdetails\default.php    Thanks in Advanced.   other problem is the rating.. virtuemart rating makes u to input a number between 1 to 5, but i want a dropdown :/

Comment: Hi. now jcomments v3.0.7 has been released. now it's time to update the modified version of jcomments v3.0.5.